# Multi Column csv file data load using sql loader

Tags: multiple-columns

I need to load a multi-line-column from .csv file to database.

Example:

student table :

```
name  , id , section, ADDRESS etc..
abc   ,1212, B,       1st cross
                      2nd main
                      bangalore
def,   2222, c,       3rd main,
                      bangalore
```

where the ADDRESS line is a multi line column, I need to implement this with sqlldr control.

Comment: You using Oracle to read, right?

Comment: and is this `\t` TAB delimited? then you could just split your columns using `\t`

Comment: Hi no its not a tab delimited. its a new line char.

Comment: ok ...You'll have to write a pre-processor to handle the line-feeds on your CSV.  CSV has no standard and Oracle doesn't state anywahere that SQL Loader doesn't support the CSV [RFC 4180|http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180] standard... SQL Loader load's data and should not be used to error with every plain text format standard the RFC 4180 standard also is not well recognized.

You'll keep on running into the same issues over and over and there are allot bad solutions on the internet that don't work.